# How to extract rows based on 2 conditions from a column

Tags: r

I have a data-frame like below, and I want to extract genes (from column 1), that have both MYB and ERF motifs (from column 2). Gene list in actual is quite long therefore cannot specify the gene names from column 1. How can I do it. Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(genes= c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A", "B", "C"),
                  motifs = c("MYB", "MYB", "MYB", "ERF", "ERF", "ERF", "ERF", "ERF", "ERF"))
```

I want genes A, B and C to be extracted based on motif MYB and ERF.

Comment: Are `MYB` and `ERF` the only `motifs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can filter to include only genes where within the group (defined by gene) at least one line has MYB and at least one line has ERF:

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  filter(any(motifs == "MYB"), any(motifs == "ERF"), .by = genes)
```

Result

```
  genes motifs
1     A    MYB
2     B    MYB
3     C    MYB
4     A    ERF
5     B    ERF
6     C    ERF
```

We could add `|>  distinct(genes)` at the end if we only want the list of such genes:

```
  genes
1     A
2     B
3     C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this if you need the desired genes only

```
> names(which(lengths(with(unique(df), split(motifs, genes))) > 1))
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `aggregate` + `any` twice:

```
aggregate(motifs ~ genes, data = df, \(x) any(x == "MYB") & any(x == "ERF")) |>
  subset(motifs == TRUE, genes)
```

If nothing else occurs in `motifs` apart from `MYB` and `ERF`, you might try the concise

```r
rowSums(table(df)) == 2L
```

where I assume `table` to be the bottle neck. If computation time matters, this might be faster:

```r
rowSums(collapse::qtab(df)) == 2L
```

If you like to return just the `genes` names:

```r
names(which(rowSums(table(df)) == 2L))
names(which(rowSums(collapse::qtab(df)) == 2L))
```

or probably faster

```r
x = rowSums(table(df)) == 2L
x[x == TRUE]
y = rowSums(collapse::qtab(df)) == 2L
y[y == TRUE]
```